# How to efficiently query with a long "WHERE IN [list]" clause?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, where-clause

I've got a database with production data in multiple tables. I want to analyze the history of the units produced and create a timeline. I am doing this in Python (jupyter lab notebook) and using a cloud based MySQL 8.0 database. Neither of the IDs (both strings and integers) is the primary ID in the database and the IDs cannot be assumed to be sequential. My current strategy is to

1. First get the IDs from the first event.
2. Do a new query with a WHERE IN [previous IDs] cluase.
3. Extract  ID's from 2.
4. Repeat 2-4 until the final stage.

The IDs are not primary keys in any table. This strategy isn't working as in one stage I have over 800 000 IDs that goes into WHERE IN clause and I can't execute it. Bonus question: Should it work, or is there a limitation in how the query can be formed (such as number of characters or length etc.)?

What I wonder is how to execute this? Is there a way to perform this in a better SQL query or should I split this into multiple queries? Can I use some Python tricks to kind of stream the data in multiple parts?

Comment: My experience is that there is an upper limit at to how many values you can use in an in-clause on mysql before performance goes bad and from my memory it is less than 1000 elements.

I would put the id's in a temporary table and do a join on that table.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Does all data come from the same database? Are the IDs indexed (doesn't need to be primary key)? What is "the final stage"? Please expain the problem behind the question. It sounds like WHERE IN is not the right way to solve the problem and you rather need joins and possibly a recursive CTE. Schema, sample data and expected result could help.

Comment: @JensMøller Indeed, tried this as the accepted answer suggested, works good.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes, the data is all from the same database and I've indexed the IDs. As the number of IDs grew I quickly realised WHERE IN was the wrong method. I've tried CTE but with the way the database is setup together with my current SQL skills that doesn't seems to be working so great. But temporary tables as suggested from others seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Well.. there is still the question: Why would you need a temporary table for something that is already in a table of the same DB?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I'm simply processing the data. I want to find all units that started to be processed in a specific time and then find all succeding events that is impossible to know when they happened and thus have to filter through where timestamp is after the start until now.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Unless you filter the fetched IDs in a way that can't be done in SQL. But consider, that using a temporary table to manipulate data can be a problem in some cases  - For example with statement based replications.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't have a specific need for a temporary table in particuar. I'm just looking for a way to get the data I want. I'd love a good query that can do it, but I haven't managed to create one yet. Then afterwards I want to analyse the data using Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have over 800 000 IDs that goes into WHERE IN clause

That's way, way too many for `IN` .

The best way to handle this kind of volume is to use a temporary table with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` and join the tables instead of using `IN`.  A temporary table can have an index so that can help speed things up for the join.

This may seem like a very heavy operation but actually it's not; mysql is very good at this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, I understand 800 000 IDs in the WHERE clause is way, way too many. Thanks. I've tried this a little and it works good. I need to practice a bit to get it right but it makes the query possible.